# How to list the top 10 most duplicate rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch the top 10 most duplicate rows from the following table:

```
Table Name: votes(id,vote)
--------------------------
1 | Taylor Swift
2 | Maroon5
3 | Maroon5
4 | Maroon5
5 | Taylor Swift
6 | Kanye West
```

Output Should be something like:

```
1. Maroon5: 3 votes
2. Taylor Swift: 2 votes
3. Kanye West: 1 votes
```

How to do that using MySQL only ( if possible )

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select vote, count(*)
from votes
group by 1
order by 2 desc
limit 10
```

Comment: @RobertPitt: He is not counting the number of values in vote column, but number of rows with the same value in vote column.

Answer (score 1):

```
select vote,count(vote) from votes group by vote order by count(vote) desc limit 10
```

Comment: Why count by all columns, and why run COUNT x2 ? you just assign it, `vote,count(vote) as count` then `ORDER BY count`

Comment: @Robert - It won't "run `count` twice at all"

Comment: Your query will not output the correct result if there are NULLs in vote column.